# Java typecasting and inheritance

Tags: java, oop, casting

I want a nice way to get the current unix timestamp from a java Date object, this is my solution:

```
public class Date extends java.util.Date {

    public int getUnixTimeStamp() {
        int unixtimestamp = (int) (this.getTime() * .001);
        return unixtimestamp;
    }
}
```

That works fine, but the problem is when I try to cast a java Date object to my custom date class, i.e:

```
Calendar foo = Calendar.getInstance();
foo.set(0, 0, 0, 12, 30);
myapp.Date foo2 = (myapp.Date)foo.getTime();
```

This generates: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to myapp.Date

I understand why this exception is made but is there any way to cast a superclass to a subclass? If not, how would you implement the unixtimestamp method? I use it quite often in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast a superclass in a subclass because the subclass may have a bigger interface than the superclass means the subclass can have functions like getUnixTimeStamp() that the superclass doesn't have. In your example that would mean you trying to call getUnixTimeStamp on a java.util.Date.

You can use a Delegate or Composition instead of inheritance here.

That means you have a Class

```
public class Date {

    private java.util.date date;

    public Date(java.util.Date date) {
        this.date = date
    }

    public int getUnixTimeStamp() {
        int unixtimestamp = (int) ((this.date.getTime()) * .001);
        return unixtimestamp;
    }
```

}

In this way you don't cast the date into your date you create a class arround the java.util.date.

If you use only this function it could be an easier solution to just create a static util function getUnixTime(Date date) that returns the changed date.

Answer (score 2):

If you're keen on having your subclass, implement a constructor in your `Date` class taking a `java.util.Date foo` and in it call `super` with `foo.getTime()`; then instead of casting you just call `Date(foo)` to instantiate your subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to make this class extend java.util.Date at all? Make a static function that takes a Date and returns the unix timestamp of that date.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you could implement it by letting the constructor of the class take the time as an input.
Something like this:

public class Date {

```
long unixtimestamp;

public Date(long time) {
    unixtimestamp = (long) (time * .001);
}

public long getUnixTimeStamp() {
    return unixtimestamp;
}
```

}

Another option is just to create a static method which converts it. It depends on whether you are planning on adding other similar features to the class or not. If not then a static-method is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't cast a type to a more derived type if the reference doesn't point to an instance of the derived type.

The `Date` being returned by `Calendar.getTime()` isn't one of your `Date` objects, and it doesn't have the additional attributes and behaviours those objects do.

You could modify your Date class to use composition instead of inheritance, e.g.

```
class Date {

    private java.util.Date date;

    public Date( java.util.Date date ) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getUnixTimestamp() {
        return (int)( date.getTime() * .001 );
    }

}
```